# Shifting magnetic field axis

Tags: vector-fields, electromagnetism

Considering the image below, I have magnetometer readings while my magnetometer is oriented along x' and y'. Can I convert these readings to get the equivalent reading if my magnetometer was oriented along x and y.

[image: Reference Image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Posts should be self-contained and, as such, external links to images are not advised. Please see: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: Is this a static field?

Comment: Do you know $\theta?$

Comment: The mathematics is as simple as providing some rotation matrix. The physics might be a different question and is outside the scope of this site.

Comment: @Aruralreader yes it is a static field. Im trying to read the geo field in a closed loop with no free currents in it.

Comment: @AdrianKeister yes theta is known.

Answer (score 0):

You have a $\mathbf{B}$ field, which we will write as
$$\left[\begin{matrix}B\cos(\alpha)\\B\sin(\alpha)\end{matrix}\right],$$
where $B=\|\mathbf{B}\|,$ the magnitude of $\mathbf{B}.$
Here $\alpha$ is measured counterclockwise from the positive $x'$ axis. Now the $x,y$ axis is rotated from the $x',y'$ axis through a *clockwise* angle of $\theta,$ which is the same as if we had rotated the vector $\mathbf{B}$ *counterclockwise* through the same angle. You can go through the exercise of multiplying the vector above by the rotation matrix
$$\left[\begin{matrix}\cos(\theta) &-\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)\end{matrix}\right],$$
but to beat to the punch, you will find that you can simplify the answer as
$$\left[\begin{matrix}B\cos(\alpha+\theta)\\B\sin(\alpha+\theta)\end{matrix}\right].$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now if I have a z-field as well which always goes into the plane(doesn't change its orientation with the above specified rotation), will it be included in the rotation calculation for the x and y axis.